# Cordova wants android-19, I have android-20

Tags: android, cordova

There are many questions here regarding problems running "cordova add platform android" command. I've tried each purposed solution and none have helped me.

**Error message**:

```
~/sandbox/hello$ cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

/home/acras/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android" from your command-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.
    at /home/acras/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:80:29
    at _fulfilled (/home/acras/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/acras/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/acras/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /home/acras/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/acras/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: /home/acras/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I did what the error message tells me (run android and installed all packages) but the error persists.

**PATH**: Android SDK home, tools and platform-tools are in the path

In the platforms folder inside android sdk I have only android-20 and android-L folders.

I guess if I add android-19 OR make cordova want android-20 will solve my problem. What should I do to achieve both options?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to download android-19?

Comment: I didn't find where to download it

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: I did run android and installed all packages it told me to, and the error persists.

Comment: Then you didn't install android-19. Run "android" again and install it.

Comment: I don't know how to install android-19

Comment: Run "android". Find "API 19". Click the Check box. Click install.

Comment: I got the same problem, but I already installed the SDK 19 and even all the others. Not working ;/

Comment: You may encounter a problem with `adb`, which reportedly doesn't exist, even it does exist. That means, you haven't installed `lib32ncurses5` and `lib32stdc++6` yet. (It happened on 64-bit Debian Jessie.)

Comment: This might help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931155/cordova-3-5-0-install-error-please-install-android-target-19

Comment: Possibly making the same mistake answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931155/cordova-3-5-0-install-error-please-install-android-target-19

Comment: Just a comment on all these comments. I got stuck on this, because downloading the SDK to version 19 **isn't the same** as adding the API to version 19. All it says is android-19, so confusion reigns somewhat!

Answer (score 6):

The current Cordova (4.1.2) only wants to build against API v19

```
> cordova build android
Running command: /Users/Duncan/Documents/Work/rescyoume/cordova/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: Please install Android target "android-19".
Hint: Run "android" from your command-line to open the SDK manager.]
```

To install v19, run `android` as it suggests and then, in the GUI that opens, select `Android 4.4.2 (API 19)/SDK Platform` in the tree and click the `Install packages...` button.

Comment: Any way to force Cordova to use the latest version of Android?

Comment: I think that may be another question worth asking here

Answer (score 1):

You need to download Android 4.4.2(API 19) because target API is set to 19 in android manifest file. Either change it to the API that you have already downloaded or download API 19

In terminal type the command

$ **android**

this will open the Android SDK manager.
Check the API 19 SDK Platform checkbox and download it.

Now when you type command

$ **cordova platform add android**

should work fine.

Answer (score -2):

If are you using Linux,

- Install ant:
  `sudo apt-get install ant`
- Export the correct sdk path:
  `export PATH=${PATH}:/<sdk path>/sdk/platform-tools:/<sdk path>/sdk/tools`