# Cordova 3.5.0 Install Error- Please Install Android Target 19

Tags: android, macos, cordova

I try to get this working and it's driving me nuts:

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

The output is:

```
Creating android project...

/Users/doekewartena/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android" from your command-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.
    at /Users/doekewartena/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:80:29
    at _fulfilled (/Users/doekewartena/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/doekewartena/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/doekewartena/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /Users/doekewartena/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/doekewartena/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: /Users/doekewartena/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

If did run the command `android` this are all the things I installed:

[image: installed]

I also did:

`open ~/.bash_profile`

And added:

`export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/doekewartena/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/doekewartena/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools`

But it doesn't help :(

Could someone help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668185/could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-your-andr

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Android SDK is not your target Android version. Target Android version 19 is the API level for android Kitkat.So in you SDK manager check if you have Android 4.4.2(API 19) installed. If you want your target API version to be different then change it in ANdroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Edit these lines. Here `android:targetSdkVersion` is your Android version that you are targeting.

[image]

Comment: You may encounter a problem with `adb`, which reportedly doesn't exist, even it does exist. That means, you haven't installed `lib32ncurses5` and `lib32stdc++6` yet. (It happened on 64-bit Debian Jessie.)

Comment: FYI i had a problem with this on Win 8 until I ran the SDK utility as Admin.  Worked after I ran elevated.

Answer (score 24):

1. Went into the SDK Manager (typing `android` into the terminal, assuming it's in your file path)
2. Selected box next to Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
3. Clicked button `Install 8 packages`
4. Ran original command (in this example `cordova platform add android`, although it could be `ionic platform add android`, depending on what you're working with)

Answer (score 7):

I too was getting the same error 19. I have no idea about AndroidManifest.xml and where it is supposed to be.

In my case, I fixed the error by running the 'android' command from the console, opening the Android 4.4.2 (API19) tree and installing the SDK Platform.

After this was installed the **cordova platform add android** command worked as desired.

Further to this I had to install a few other elements of API19 to be able to create an android emulator:

- ARM EABI v7a System Image
- Intel x86 Atom System Image
- Google APIs (x86 System Image)
- Google APIs (ARM System Image)

I could then create an emulator based on API19 using the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager that is included in the android SDK bundle.

Answer (score 4):

I also had to change project.properties in the same directory

```
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation on how you set up an AndroidManifest.xml document.
Every app should have one.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: The command `cordova platform add android` is supposed to create the base android app. This command is failing, so there is no android app, and no AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If your having issues installing the package, ensure you are running 'Android Central' as an administrator... took me 30 mins to work it out!!