# Apache cordova add platform android error

Tags: android, cordova

I try the command `>cordova platform add android`

and here's what I get:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Workspaces\cordova\hello>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\Daniel\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_mo
dules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Failed to run "android". Make sure you have the latest Android SDK instal
led, and that the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your
PATH.
    at C:\Users\Daniel\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\
lib\check_reqs.js:43:27
    at exithandler (child_process.js:644:7)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:660:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:808:12)
Error: C:\Users\Daniel\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\
create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

As far as I can tell, my Path is set right.

```
ANDROID_HOME  C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\

Path %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;etc
```

Previously I had my path set explicitly with the same error (`Path C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;etc`). I've tried several different combinations to try to get it to work, but I always get the same error. My Android SDK is up do date. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that when I updated the Path, I erased the default values in there. For windows 7 it was

`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

Then append to the end of that. Doing this gave me a new error:

```
Error: Please install Android target "android-19"
```

From here it was clear to me what to do, but if anyone else runs across this, here is a solution to the second error: [Cordova 3.5.0 Install Error- Please Install Android Target 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931155/cordova-3-5-0-install-error-please-install-android-target-19)