# cordova android installation failed?

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, ionic-framework

I am new to Cordova.I try to install android platform it seems failed.

[image]

My Environment Variables paths:

```
C:\Users\reegan\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;
C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs;
C:\Users\reegan\android-sdks;
C:\Users\reegan\android-sdks\tools
```

Comment: i dont think i has anything to do with your environment variables, it says in the log that you need to install android-19, you have to open your android SDK manager and install/update all your sdk's

Comment: @JRowan I installed Latest android version Android 5.0(API 21).It is work well in my eclipse android apps.

Comment: is your SDK manager fully updated?

Comment: @JRowan yes.I think want to install Android 4.4.2(API 19)(target 19).It found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931155/cordova-3-5-0-install-error-please-install-android-target-19

Comment: @JRowan can you send your Hangouts id.