# Cannot Add Android Platform on phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, cross-platform, phonegap-plugins

I'm getting this error
[image]

I tried to execute the command `phonegap platform add android` on the command prompt inorder to get the `cordova-X.X.X.jar` file which enables me to use

```
import org.apache.cordova.Config;
import org.apache.cordova.Droidgap;
```

on Android Studio

My System Variables are as follows

```
ANDROID_HOME=E:\Android\sdk\
ANT_HOME=C:\ant\
ANT_OPTS=-Xmx256M
JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\
Path= .... C:\Program Files\nodejs\;%ANT_HOME%\bin\;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\;
```

I have to `extend` my `MainActivity` class to `DroidGap` and run `super.loadURL("linktomyindexfile");` command.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it done..

added the following to `Path`

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\
```

added this as a system variable

```
ANDROID_HOME=E:\Android\sdk
```

installed SDK Tools for API V19 using SDK Manager after I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931155/cordova-3-5-0-install-error-please-install-android-target-19) error.

After that the command ran smoothly

[image]