# Cordova tool for Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I tried install Visual Studio 2015 RC on windows 10 (build 10074) , and create blank cordova project , but i get as follow error message , and i tried reinstall visual studio 2015 rc many times , but can't resolve this .

Android Package: extra-android-support One or more required packages are missing.

Android Package: android-19 One or more required packages are missing.

Android Package: sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-19 One or more required packages are missing.

Android Package: sys-img-x86-android-19 One or more required packages are missing.

Android Package: addon-google_apis_x86-google-19 One or more required packages are missing.

Android Package: addon-google_apis-google-19 One or more required packages are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Android SDK and install the missing packages

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reinstall Visual Studio. You need to install Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordoba, read first about them here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771545%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: Hi , I install Visual Studio 2015 for full , so i think that include  tools for Apache cordova

Comment: check Android SDK. Also look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931155/cordova-3-5-0-install-error-please-install-android-target-19

Comment: thank you , use android sdk manager install the missing packages and it's work

Answer (score 0):

1.Open **Android SDK Manager** as Administrator mode.
2.Install the missing packages