# How to debug Ionic app on Android device from Visual Studio

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, ripple

I have an Ionic app that I can debug in Visual Studio 2015 using Ripple. I now want to debug in a tablet that has Android 4.2.2 installed.

So I downloaded the jsHybugger app as described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757061.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#DbgAndroid) (except I didn't purchase a license, so skipped step 5 - "Place the jshybugger_license.xml file in the root of your project").

Now I hit a problem when I select "Device" as the debug target. I get this error:

> MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD10205: Please install Android target ""

So I opened Android SDK manager and installed everything under the 4.2.2 target. I then got a new error:

> Unable to start program 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'

I don't use Eclipse, and there is another copy of adb.exe in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`, so I uninstalled Eclipse and ran a repair on the Visual Studio 2015 installation.

I then got (the command being ....cordova\build.bat):

> Command failed with exit code 2

I went to Tools-> Options-> Tools For Apache Cordova -> Cordova Tools -> Clear cache, and this caused a fresh install of the Cordova tools. However I still get the "Command failed with exit code 2" error.

How do I fix this mess?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while ago, and by following the steps [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931155/cordova-3-5-0-install-error-please-install-android-target-19#answer-24934188) solved it for me.

Ensure that you have Android version 19 installed. I was targeting Jelly Bean, and I still got this error...